# Ввод данных в массив string

Tags: java

Как ввести данные в массив string?

```
string choice = (string) System.in.read();
```

Comment: а че не получается? не считая, что стринг в большой буквы надо бы

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    String str;
    BufferedReader in=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    str=in.readLine(); //Читаем с клавиатуры
    System.out.println("твоя строка = "+str);
```

если хочется вводить много текста и хранить в стринге - лучше использовать StringBuilder();

Answer (score 0):

Массив типа String насколько помню не изменяем(строка(String) является объектом), а следовательно перед тем как "вводить данные в массив" следует их принять(сформировать)...Массив String объявляется так: String [] string...как то так...а в общем смысл вопроса не очень ясен...

Comment: А как можно зделать что бы ис строки a выводить напр "vvv"?

String a="tyy vvv hjjj dfsf gdrghg jtyjtyj tykyuk uiluiliuo lioio; iooio kkhm";

Comment: не правильно

Comment: @DJK, вам нужен [String.split](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String))